# python How to sort list of string by digit=string

Tags: python

how to sort following python list

```
nlist = [
"494=Deploy\00000001.inx",
"19=Deploy\0000000144.exe",
"2=Deploy\00000001_index.dat",
"9=Deploy\0000001b_index.bin",
"1=Deploy\00000001_index.bin",
"7=Deploy\00000019_index.bin",
"2=Deploy\00000001_Onedata.dat",
"19=Deploy\000000024444.exe"
]
```

to following

```
sortedList = [
"1=Deploy\00000001_index.bin",
"2=Deploy\00000001_index.dat",
"2=Deploy\00000001_Onedata.dat",
"7=Deploy\00000019_index.bin",
"9=Deploy\0000001b_index.bin",
"19=Deploy\0000000144.exe",
"19=Deploy\000000024444.exe",
"494=Deploy\00000001.inx",
]
```

can it be possible to make it single liner

Comment: `sorted(nlist, key=lambda m: int(m.split('=')[0]))`

Comment: Thanks Avinash and Danidee

Answer (score 2):

sort the list and pass a key that splits the strings in the list on `'='` and picks the numeric part, `nlist.sort` modifies the original list, if you want a new list you're better off with `sorted()`

```
nlist.sort(key=lambda x: int(x.split('=')[0]))
print(nlist)
```

Output

```
['1=Deploy\x0000001_index.bin', '2=Deploy\x0000001_index.dat', '2=Deploy\x0000001_Onedata.dat', '7=Deploy\x0000019_index.bin', '9=Deploy\x000001b_index.bin', '19=Deploy\x000000144.exe', '19=Deploy\x00000024444.exe', '494=Deploy\x0000001.inx']
```